# enabling pthread on vscode using code runner extension on linux wsl?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pthreads, posix, vscode-code-runner

I have encountered an error on Linux while using Posix threads with Code runner on VS Code- an error of undefined reference to pthread_create();

Answer (score 0):

To fix it please add -pthread argument in code runner settings.json:

```
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -pthread -o $fileNameWithoutExt &&
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).